# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl

Tags: compilation, installation, ld, caffe

I'm trying to compile caffe, While running `make all` command, I have got this linking error:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:566: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your Makefile.config change the following:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial

LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
```

Please note that the path may vary depending on your OS.